# Android Crash Reports - Whats the best way to get the most information?

Tags: android, acra

I would like to know how others are finding the Android SDK version number and device info in crash reports for applications in production. How do you know if its on a Samsung Galaxy Infuse running Android 2.3?  I am considering using ACRA for a an app that has millions of downloads, however I am not going to introduce a new library like ACRA in the code base without some significant justification and recommendation in terms of what apps are using ACRA.

One approach that has been identified is to upload the information w/o an API to a spreadsheet:
    See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11217508/android-crash-handler-to-upload-info-to-google-spreadsheet

Comment: If you are weary of using the library, you can manually make the POST HttpRequests that are needed to upload the data to a docs spreadsheet / form. That way you also get to pick and choose exactly what data you want to upload.

Comment: Well I am weary of using any library.  I need to get a sense of who is using ACRA and what are the benefits/risks.

Comment: I have before, but I have not implemented it recently. If you choose to manually execute your own requests to the google spreadsheet then there is no need for a library.

Comment: Where could you place such code? And would this be a series of http requests or just one upload?

Comment: Is there a place for a global exception handler or something?

Comment: Tim, I have placed a separate question to explore this approach: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11217508/android-crash-handler-to-upload-info-to-google-spreadsheet

Comment: You can set it up with Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler(). And it is only 1 upload per row in the spreadsheet.

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you start implementing your own Google spreadsheet crash report uploader... why don't you want to use ACRA ? The latest version 4.2.3 is on year old (it IS stable), has been downloaded more than 10000 times and is used in major apps... like... Facebook, Shazam, Winamp. A new beta version will come in the first weeks of august.

See for yourself: http://www.appbrain.com/stats/libraries/details/acra/acra

When you can take benefit of 2 years of experience in implementing something you need, why implement it yourself ?

If the whole ACRA lib looks frightening to you (even if it takes 5 minutes to set it up), you can just have a look to the source and pick the GoogleFormSender class.

Feel free to contact me if you have any question regarding ACRA.